# Set search bar in SP2013 document set to search only document set

Tags: 2013, search, document-set

In our SP 2013 on premise installation, the search bar in a document set returns documents and document sets from the entire library. What I would like is to limit the search to the document set itself. So the results should come only from documents and eventual folders within that specific document set.

How can I achieve this?

In the snapshot below, I've highlighted the search bar I refer to. The results below the bar show another document set, and documents from other document sets, while the document set itself has documents that should be returned.

My users expect rightly that a search bar in a document set searches only that set.

[image]